# How can I get the current value of a Subject exposed as an IObservable?

Tags: .net, system.reactive, observable

I have a `User` model that has an `IObservable<int>` property. This property is backed by a `BehaviorSubject` that is initialized with a certain value. How can I get the current value of the observable, without having to expose another property that accesses the `.Value` property on the underlying `BehaviorSubject`?

This is the sample model to consider:

```cs
class User
{
    private readonly BehaviorSubject<int> mySubject;

    public User()
    {
        mySubject = new BehaviorSubject<int>(100);
    }

    public IObservable<int> Value => mySubject.DistinctUntilChanged();

    public void SomeMethod(int level)
    {
        mySubject.OnNext(level);
    }
}
```

Notice that I have a method that calls `OnNext` on the subject with the specified value. This is already strange to me, it would be better if I could just treat the `Value` observable as a get and set property but alas...

On another part of my code, I need to imperatively get the current value for a given user, and I can't seem to find a way to do that from the `IObservable` interface directly. I tried using both the `Latest` and `MostRecent` methods, but they seem to do different things than what I would expect. When trying both, my application blocks indefinitely.

The only way I found to properly expose the value was to create another property for the "current" value, like this:

```cs
public int CurrentValue => mySubject.Value;
```

I don't like this because it feels to me that I'm being redundant. Is there a better way to expose the current value of the observable so that external code can just get the value and do what it wants with it? For that matter, as I commented earlier, I'm also not very happy having another method to mutate the value. It makes the interface of the object cumbersome in my view. In knockoutjs for instance, I can get and set the value just by "calling" the observable, which seems simpler. In this case this would be equivalent to `Value()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can always do one of these, depending on whether you're in an `async` context or not:

```
var value = await user.Value.FirstAsync();
var value = user.Value.First();
```

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
class User
{
    private readonly BehaviorSubject<int> valueSubject;
    public int Value
    {
        get { return valueSubject.Value; }
        set { valueSubject.OnNext(value); }
    }
    public IObservable<int> ValueChanged => valueSubject.DistinctUntilChanged();

    public User()
    {
        valueSubject = new BehaviorSubject<int>(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: For current value, wouldn't it be `Value.Last()`?